# How to store the number 365 on 8 bits

Tags: numbers, storage, bit

Just a little background: initially when the application was designed (well, more than 15 years ago), our customer assured us, that their business plan never will change, thus the application was designed.

The application manages certificates, which according to the country's law by our customer must be renewed every half year (180 days), and these certificates are stored on smart cards, which are distributed to various staffing entities belonging to our customer.

These smart cards are used to access various on-site systems, and the smart card reader automatically adjusts values on them according to its needs, such as decrementing the number of remaining days. When this number reaches zero the card is re-issued with the initial 180 number again

The smart cards are tightly packed with various information, among them am 8 bit value, telling how many days are left. Because someone, 15 years ago never thought that in 15 years the law will change and they thought that 8 bits should be enough for everyone.

Obviously, now a change request came in from the customer ... telling us that there is a plan to change the law to allow the existing certificates to extend to 1 year ...

And here comes the question: How can we store 365 on 8 bits ... any hacks are welcome.

Comment: Can you lower the resolution when the number is high? 12 months remaining... 11 months... 10 months... then at 180 days switch to days?

Comment: You are asking us to do something impossible. You want to store more than 8 bits of information into 8 bits of storage. We need some information about the system before we can suggest a hack. Do you know anything about the number of days except that it's an integer that's nine bits of length? Can you tell if it should be odd or even? Greater than 100? Do you mind losing precision?

Comment: One hack to provide low resolution counters is to drop the lowest bit and on each decrement toss a coin to see if the decrement goes through. Is that okay in your case?

Comment: Does the smart card actually store the number of days remaining, and is this decremented daily? How does the system ensure that a decrement happens once per day, no more, no less?

Comment: Are you sure you can't spare one more unused single bit (or even larger number) in some other field to get 9 bits in total?

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner The cards have an ID, the smartcard reader is connected to a computer, which is connected to a central system (in-house), which keeps track of already updated cards, so that not every entrance on a door will decrease the counter.

Comment: @Stan Indeed, that's what we were looking into, the ID mentioned in my other comment is a 16 bit value, and now the number of issued cards is below 10000 so if we hijack one of the bits from there we could do some magic and the problems will come when there will be more than 32767 cards

Comment: @fritzone when a central computer tracks the cards anyway, why does the number of days remaining need to be stored on the card? The database on the central computer would store an expiration date for each card, no need to store anything on the card itself except it's ID.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner It's due to legacy and history ... The very initial system (15 years ago) had only 1 validator (on the main door of the building), connected to 1 computer doing all the work, and the validator was there to validate, and not to open the door. But the company grew, became more security aware and since then these validators are connected to mechanisms which opens the door upon a successful validation :) and the backend system also grew in size leading to a central validation server signaling back to the "door computer" that yes, allow this person inside :(

Comment: you cant compress 9 bits of info into 8 bits without losing information, not possible, there is no magic that can do it without losing information.  the answer you selected is both not compatible with your prior system and is lossy it loses information.  since it is now okay to be incompatible with the prior system and/or lose information you should have just found a 9th bit.  detected legacy from new systems and handled them accordingly.  if the customer is willing to take a new solution to adapt to the new law they...are willing to take a new solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm suggesting another approach: can you modify the smart card reader to decrement the counter every 2 days?
So you'll need to count up to 183 (for leap years).

**edit**
There is also room for a *leap year* bit, assuming you reverse the counting logic.
If you count from 0 to 182 (days from 0 to 364), after the counter reaches 160 (128+32) `1010 0000` the bit in position 7 is no longer changed.

```
if (dayCount >= 160) {
    realDayCount = dayCount & 0xBF;   // 1011 1111
    leapFlag = dayCount & 0x40;       // 0100 0000
}
```